# Banding in Premiere preview

Tags: premiere, after-effects, cs5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gradient banding](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/gradient-banding)

I have a video imported in Adobe Premier from After effect (16 bits).

Before rendered in the timeline the [image looks nice](http://flic.kr/p/czePj5) but when rendered I have a important **banding** (see [photo 2](http://flic.kr/p/czeQ6q) (no banding) and [3 (with banding)](http://flic.kr/p/czePkW))

Because it is only on the rendered video in the timeline this must be a codec issue (correct me if I am wrong).

What is the best codec and settings to use in order to have a nice preview and nice final video ?

Comment: because I have no reputation I can not add any link nor images.

Comment: But I can add it the comment. Here is the original file : http://flic.kr/p/czePj5, a close-up on the nice gradient : http://flic.kr/p/czeQ6q and a close-up on the banded gradient in premier : http://flic.kr/p/czePkW

Comment: I checked this answer but the banding is not in the video, the problem lies in the codec / export.

Comment: Actually, in looking at the images on a decent monitor at home, it looks like what you have is not banding but compression artifacts. Can you change it to a higher quality setting.